# In WebJobs SDK, How to bind additional CloudStorageAccount for Blob output?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

`WebJobs SDK` is doing wonderful job simplifying amount of code one need to write to save blobs to storage, but all within ONE storage account that is the default `AzureJobsStorage`.

Having everything (Queues,Blobs,Tables, and Heartbeats) in one storage account will throttle that account in medium-load production environment.

Of course, I can write legacy `WindowsAzure.Storage` code to save blobs to desired storage account, but I will loose the **simplicity** of the `WebJobs SDK`.

Appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, the WebJobs SDK supports only two Storage accounts per host:

- `AzureWebJobsStorage` - used for your app's data
- `AzureWebJobsDashboard` - used for logging (heartbeats, functions, etc) and dashboard indexing

The two accounts can be different if you want but that's all the separation you can do for now.

We have an item on the backlog to support multiple storage accounts for data but there is no ETA for it.

Comment: Thank you Victor for clarifying, lets hope we will see multiple storage accounts after RC1.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack around the limitation, but let's say you want specific jobs associated with storage accounts (instead of one job accessing and writing to different storage accounts). You could open two different job hosts with different configs, but also create your own `TypeLocator` to filter which jobs are associated with specific hosts.